# How to add nil into Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, null, option-type

I'd like to add nil into Array,set as answersBody.

```
var answersBody = [String]()
```

When answer_body is nil, it returns error.Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

```
  Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/questions/index",parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
            var jsonObj = JSON(data!)
            var questions_count = jsonObj["questions"].count

            for var index = 0; index < questions_count; index++ {
                let answer_body = jsonObj["questions"][index]["answers"]["body"].string
                self.answersBody.append(answer_body!)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make array type [String?] which is optional string. It can be set to nil. Regular String type can't be nil.

And then

```
if let body = answerBody{
    self.answersBody.append(body)
}
else{
    self.answersBody.append(nil)
}
```

let would unwrap your optional. If it's not nil, then it would enter into if; otherwise else would execute.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add a nil value to an array that doesn't accept nil values.

Try this:

For the array initialization:

`var answersBody = [String?]()`

And for when appending a value, remove the exclamation mark

```
self.answersBody.append(answer_body)
```

Reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: Thx your help! However, it still return error. I've decided to use conditional judgement as following. 
if answer_body != nil{
~~~
}else{
}

Answer (score 0):

I used an array of String optionals as the two previous answers suggested and didn't work for me, i use this instead:

```
var arrayValues: [AnyObject?] = [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil]
```